# CSS Classname with ReactJS

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx

```
 import classes from './NavBar.module.css';
```

then in the file I am trying to access the css module like this

```
        <ul className={classes.navbar-nav}>
            <li>Home</li>
        </ul>
```

In my CSS Module file

```
.navbar-nav {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

The error I get is

```
'nav' is not defined  no-undef
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `classes["navbar-nav"]`. You can't use the dot operator because name variables cannot have `-`.

For a better understanding, read about [naming of javascript variables](https://www.dummies.com/web-design-development/javascript/naming-javascript-variables/)

Comment: That worked but why didn't i use the dot (.) operator?

Comment: Because name variable cannot has "-". You need to read about naming of js variable

Comment: https://www.dummies.com/web-design-development/javascript/naming-javascript-variables/